# Trouble setting table width using Python Docx

Tags: python, width, python-docx, word-table

i have to create numerous pdfs of tables every year, so i was trying to write a script with Docx to create the table in Word with each column having its own set width and left or right alignment. Right now i am working on two tables - one with 262 rows, the other with 1036 rows.
The code works great for the table with 262 rows, but will not set column widths correctly for the table with 1036 rows. Since the code is identical for both tables, i am thinking it is a problem with the data itself, or possibly the size of the table? I tried creating the second larger table without any data, and the widths are correct. I then tried creating the table below with a subset of the 7 rows from the 1036 rows, including the rows with the largest numbers of characters, in case a column was not wrapping the text but instead was forcing the column widths to change. It runs fine - widths are correct. I use the exact same code on the full data set of 1036 rows, and the widths change. Any ideas?

Below is the code for only 7 rows of data. it works correctly - the first column is 3.5", the second and third columns are 1.25 inches.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Cm, Pt, Inches
import docx
from docx.enum.text import WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH
from docx.enum.table import WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL
year = '2019'

set_width_dic = {
'PUR'+year +'_subtotals_indexed_by_site.txt':(Inches(3.50), Inches(1.25), Inches(1.25)),
'PUR'+year +'_subtotals_indexed_by_chemical.txt':(Inches(3.50), Inches(1.25), Inches(1.25))}

set_alignment_dic = {
'PUR'+year +'_subtotals_indexed_by_site.txt':[[0,WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.LEFT, 'Commodity or site'],[1,WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT, 'Pounds Applied'],[2,WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT, 'Agricultural Applications']],
'PUR'+year +'_subtotals_indexed_by_chemical.txt':[[0,WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.LEFT, 'Chemical'],[1,WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT, 'Pounds Applied'],[2,WD_ALIGN_PARAGRAPH.RIGHT, 'Agricultural Applications']]}

#the data
list_of_lists = ['Chemical', 'Pounds Applied', 'Agricultural Applications'],['ABAMECTIN', '51,276.54', '69,659'],['ABAMECTIN, OTHER RELATED', '0.03', 'N/A'], ['S-ABSCISIC ACID', '1,856.38', '230'],['ACEPHATE', '158,054.76', '11,082'],['SULFUR','49,038,554.00','170,396'],['BACILLUS SPHAERICUS 2362, SEROTYPE H5A5B, STRAIN ABTS 1743 FERMENTATION SOLIDS, SPORES AND INSECTICIDAL TOXINS','11,726.29','N/A']

doc = docx.Document() # Create an instance of a word document
col_ttl = 3 # add enough columns as headings in the first list in list_of_lists
row_ttl =7# add rows to equal total number lists in list_of_lists
# Creating a table object
table = doc.add_table(rows= row_ttl, cols= col_ttl)
table.style='Light Grid Accent 1'
for r in range(len(list_of_lists)):
    row=table.rows[r]
    widths = set_width_dic[file] #Ex of widths = (Inches(3.50), Inches(1.25), Inches(1.25))
    for c, cell in enumerate(table.rows[r].cells):#c is an index, cell is the empty cell of the table, 
        table.cell(r,c).vertical_alignment = WD_ALIGN_VERTICAL.BOTTOM
        table.cell(r,c).width = widths[c]
        par = cell.add_paragraph(str(list_of_lists[r][c]))
        for l in set_alignment_dic[file]:
            if l[0] == c:
                par.alignment = l[1] 
doc.save(path+'try.docx')
```

When i try to do the exact same code for the entire list_of_lists (a list of 1036 lists), the widths are incorrect: column 1 = 4.23", column 2 = 1.04", and column 3 = 0.89"

I printed the full 1036 row list_of_lists on my cmd box, then pasted it in a text file thinking i might be able to include it here. However when i attempted to run the full list, it would not paste back into the cmd box - it gave an EOL error, and only showed the first 65 lists in the list_of_lists. DocX is able to make the full table, just wont set the correct widths. I am baffled. I have looked through every StackExchange python Docx table width post i can find, and many other googled sites. Any thoughts much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Just figured out the issue. I needed to add autofit = False. Now the code works for the longer table as well

```
        table.autofit = False 
        table.allow_autofit = False
```

Comment: Thank you Thank you Thank you. This has been driving me crazy.